# Event handler reports element undefined when used inside a class

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this simple, working code using JavaScript event handlers.

```js
var testElement = document.getElementById('test');
testElement.addEventListener('click', updateValue);

function updateValue() {
  testElement.innerHTML = 'test';
}
```

```html
<div id="test">click me</div>
```

But if I attempt to refactor this as a JavaScript `class`, the event handler throws an error, saying that `testElement` is undefined.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.testElement = document.getElementById('test');
    this.testElement.addEventListener('click', this.updateValue);
  }
  
  updateValue() {
    this.testElement.innerHTML = 'test';
  }
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
```

```html
<div id="test">Click Me</div>
```

The error message says:

```
Error {
  "message": "TypeError: this.testElement is undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 19,
  "colno": 5
}
```

Why is this? What can I do to mitigate this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `updateValue` function as a parameter and when the `updateValue` function is called `this` keyword does not refer to the `MyClass` instance you thought. You need to be able to pass the referance.

You can handle this with an arrow function in ES6:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.testElement = document.getElementById('test');
    this.testElement.addEventListener('click',
      e => this.updateValue()
    );
  }

  updateValue() {
    this.testElement.innerHTML = 'test';
  }
}

  var myClass = new MyClass();
```